# Delete value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do you delete one value in MongoDB as opposed to an entire key?

For example I have a key "hello" that contains the following data:

```
> db.Data.find({'id': 'hello'}, {'_id':0}).pretty()
{
        "id" : "hello",
        "Foo" : BinData(0,"1="),
        "Bar" : BinData(0,"1="),
        "Baz" : BinData(0,"1=="),
}
```

Now If I try to filter for a value "Foo" in my delete statement it does not delete.

```
> db.fileData.deleteOne({"id": "hello", "Foo": 0})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 0 }
```

I just want to delete one value "Foo" not the entire key "hello", how do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/sJV0IXBjwwz

Use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

```
db.fileData.updateOne(
   { id : "hello" }, // query
   { $unset: { Foo: "" } } // update $unset will remove Foo
)
```